# How to auto clear NSUserDefault values in swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

How can I auto clear the `nsuserdefault` values in swift?  I have already tried this but it doesn't work for me...

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary] forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

Comment: So, if you are using Swift, why is your code in Objective-C? Hmmm?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

check how many keys are already stored

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array.count)
```

add just another key

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "justAnotherKey1")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "justAnotherKey2")
```

check how many keys are already stored again (+2)

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array.count)
```

now create a loop to remove your object for the keys

```
for key in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key.description)
}
```

check how many keys you have again

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array.count)
```

update: **Xcode 7.2.1 • Swift 2.1.1** (note NSUserDefaults doesn't work in playground anymore, so it needs to be tested in a real project)

```
print(Array(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys).count)

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "justAnotherKey1")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "justAnotherKey2")

print(Array(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys).count)

for key in Array(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key)
}

print(Array(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys).count)
```

Comment: `.array` is not needed

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus, this is a overkill. you can simply do that in a line just like objective-c. check my answer

Answer (score 71):

The swift counterpart for your objective-c code is this

```
 let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!

 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain)
```

**Swift 3.0 and higher**

```
let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3.0 Solution**

```
let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
defaults.setObject(nil, forKey: "userEmail")
```

doing that, you put nil, so you clear

Comment: this does work but there is a method for that called removeObjectForKey

Comment: @LeoDabus, you right but removeObjectForKey will not work with all, like replacing or removing UserAgent at run time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "auto clear". Just get all the existing NSUserDefaults keys and set them all to nil.

To get all the keys, get the NSUserDefaults `dictionaryRepresentation` and get its `keys` (`allKeys` in Objective-C).