# How to remove all UserDefaults data ? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have this code to remove all `UserDefaults` data from the app:

```
let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)

print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys).count)
```

But I got `10` from the print line. Shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: Check this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797096/delete-all-keys-from-a-nsuserdefaults-dictionary-ios#6797133

Comment: @RyanPoolos I tried many solutions , I'm getting the same result `10`

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The problem is you are printing the UserDefaults contents, right after clearing them, but you are not manually synchronizing them.

```
let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys).count)
```

This should do the trick.

Now you don't normally need to call `synchronize` manually, as the system does periodically synch the userDefaults automatically, but if you need to push the changes immediately, then you need to force update via the `synchronize` call.

[The documentation states this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)

> Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.

Comment: Actually when I saw `synchronize()` in @Ryan Poolos answer I tried to use it and exactly like you , but still getting `10` when I print. Thanks

Comment: Which keys are present? Try printing them to see

Comment: AppleLanguages, AppleLocale, NSInterfaceStyle, AppleITunesStoreItemKinds, AppleKeyboardsExpanded, PKKeychainVersionKey, ApplePasscodeKeyboards , AppleKeyboards, NSLanguages, NSInterfaceStyle  ... I really don't know what are these things

Comment: @Zizoo there is some keys that can't be cleared check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27833340/2303865

Comment: so when the count of keys is 10 , that means I have cleared all keys ?

Comment: Well if you don't see any off your keys, obviously

Comment: I have no idea how many but you just need to removePersistentDomain and thats it

Comment: You should update your answer to what actually answered the question rather than the suggestion to use synchronize.

Comment: no need to force synchronize and no need to create a new array object to get the keys count `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.count`

Answer (score 87):

This answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6797133/563381 but just incase here it is in Swift.

```
func resetDefaults() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let dictionary = defaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
    dictionary.keys.forEach { key in
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got `10` again :(

Comment: you never use `value`, so you should ignore it with `_`

Comment: or better yet: `defaults.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.forEach(defaults.removeObject(forKey:)`

Comment: from offical documentation about the syncrhonize() function: "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used"

Comment: At the time this answer was written I think it was often necessary, but you're absolutely right at this point in time it is a deprecated function we no longer need on any modern iOS version. Updated the answer to cover that.

Comment: Alexander's code was great. But it was missing a character.  Should be:     `defaults.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.forEach(defaults.removeObject(forKey:))`